# Is reboot the same as init 6?

Tags: reboot, init

Is reboot the same as init 6 for ubuntu?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2. When ssh'ed into the box I can type `runlevel` and I get:

```
N 2
```

Looking at `man reboot` I see that:

> When called with --force or when in runlevel 0 or 6, this tool invokes the reboot(2) system call itself and directly reboots the system.  Otherwise this simply invokes the shutdown(8) tool with the appropriate arguments.

If I read `man shutdown 8` I see:

> shutdown arranges for the system to be brought down in a safe way.  All logged-in users are notified that the system is going down and, within the last five minutes of TIME, new logins are prevented.

My basic understanding about the difference between `reboot` and `init 6` is:

- On other distros and perhaps older distros `reboot` would just unmount the disks and basically flick the power switch without running any shutdown scripts
- `init 6` will run all of the shutdown scripts in `/etc/init/rc.*` as it reduces system's runlevel
- On newer versions of Ubuntu the `reboot` command without `--force` or `-f` will run the shutdown command which does would basically do the same thing as `init 6`
- It's probably better to get in the habit of using `init 6` instead of `reboot` as it is safer and would work better cross-distro, but the default behavior of `reboot` has been changed to try and prevent errors / dataloss if someone does use it.

Is that about right? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is really never any compelling reason to use `init 6` instead of `reboot`, unless:

- For some reason you are missing the `reboot` executable, *or*
- You are deliberately trying to avoid notifying users that the system is going down.

**`reboot` (so long as you don't run `reboot --force`) is actually the "softer" way to shut down.**

Consider:

> `init 6` will run all of the shutdown scripts in `/etc/init/rc.*` as it reduces system's runlevel

But [the `reboot` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/reboot.8.html), called *without* the `--force` flag, only directly reboots the system (via [the `reboot` system call](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/reboot.2.html)) when one of these two situations applies:

- The system is in [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevels) 0 (single user mode), so there is no reduction of runlevel that *can* occur, so no shutdown scripts are automatically run.
- The system is in runlevel 6. *What `init 6` does it to put the system in runlevel 6.* Again, there's nothing running `init 6` will do that running the `reboot` command won't do.

Otherwise, `sudo reboot` is equivalent to `sudo shutdown -r now`. This does all the nice things `sudo init 6` does, but also:

- notifies users that the system is going down.
- prevents new logins (though they probably wouldn't succeed anyway).
- **is more intuitive and self-documenting than `sudo init 6`**.

If you're on a system with only you logged in, and only local logins, **there is nothing wrong with using `init 6` to reboot.** If that's how you prefer to reboot, then by all means, go ahead--you're not harming anything by doing so. But there's also nothing objectively preferable about doing it this way.

**`init`'s own documentation says it's not the normal way to shut down or reboot the system.** Consider that when `init` is run by the user (like when you run `sudo init 6`), it actually runs `telinit` (see [`man init`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/init.8.html)). `telinit` is what actually changes runlevels. And [`man telinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/telinit.8.html) tells us:

> Normally  you  would  use  the  [shutdown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/shutdown.8.html)(8)  tool to halt or reboot
>   the system, or to bring it down to single-user mode.

Comment: I have Alienware X51 dell pc, where i have installed Ubuntu 13.04 and kernel 3.11. When i do $ init 6 , it reboots and sometimes BIOS keep showing forever. IS it because i am using init 6 and not reboot command?

Comment: @YumYumYum I don't see why using `init 6` would cause this. When you use `reboot` instead of `init 6`, does it always get past the BIOS?

Comment: I have updated the BIOS firmware from A00 to A02, since then my reboot or init 6 both works so it seems like BIOS issue was. Thank you.

Comment: Running `reboot` halts sometimes on my Ubuntu Server 14.02 of single user and local login only. Is it safe I always do `sync` followed by a `reboot -f`?