# How to switch to a command-line console

Tags: command-line

I have just upgraded my system but it boots to Low Graphics mode by default. I have seen questions on how to solve this problem and they all suggest to run a couple of commands from a command-line interface.

But there isn't any command-line console by default in Low Graphics mode and hence, I cannot run those commands. And, the answers I saw to solve the problem doesn't explain this situation either.

How to switch to a command-line console in order to run the commands in Low Graphics mode?

Comment: @karel the duped question has information on both problems, how to fix low graphics mode, and how to get a command line console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open a text-only console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only virtual console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. To reboot the system from the console run the command: `sudo reboot`. Press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to exit from the virtual console. In Ubuntu 17.10 and later press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to exit from the virtual console.
5. Sometimes if you just run the command: `sudo reboot` from the console, your computer will boot to your normal login screen when it reboots. This does not work every time or in all situations, but you may want to try it once anyway. Also this way of getting to your normal login screen is a workaround that does not fix anything, so you will still need to do something to [fix your low-graphics mode problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).

Comment: Thank you so much it works now one question though whats the difference between "init 6" and "shutdown -r"thanks so much it works now

Comment: There is really never any compelling reason to use `init 6` instead of reboot, unless for some reason you are missing the reboot executable, or you are deliberately trying to avoid notifying users. **reboot (so long as you don't run reboot --force) is actually the "softer" way to shut down.** Visit the source of the preceding quotation to read the explanation in the rest of Eliah Kagan's answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175486/is-reboot-the-same-as-init-6/175490#175490

Comment: You can log in to 6 different consoles and switch between them. `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `<F1 / F2 / F3 / F4 / F5 / F6>`  (`F7` is the login console that you usually see.)

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the cli by pressing ctrl+alt+F1 (to get back to the gui just press ctrl+alt+F7)