# Input not supported Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, resolution

After installing the AMD Catalyst driver  which I downloaded from the AMD website, it asked me to reboot and after that I got a black screen with "Input not supported".

[image]

I know it's the graphics problem, also the grub menu recovery mode didn't help. I want the 1366×768 resolution. I'm absolutely new to Ubuntu, and this is very frustrating.

Comment: Amd catalyst driver from the website

Comment: Is there a file in your filesystem from the AMD Catalyst driver at this path: `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`?

Comment: Since it has installed properly, there must be, but i cannot access it because i cannot see anything.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438783/how-to-switch-to-a-command-line-console-in-order-to-run-the-commands-in-low-grap/438804#438804). This answer tells you how to login to a text-only console. Then run this command and comment about the results: `cd /usr/share/ati/ && ls`. The command will tell you if there is a file called `fglrx-uninstall.sh` in the `/usr/share/ati/` directory.

Comment: Is there a way to uninstall it from the grub (shift) menu?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to uninstall the Catalyst driver from a text-only console (NOT from the grub menu), and there is also a way to install the AMD proprietary driver from the Ubuntu Software Center from a text-only console. You can open a text-only console from the grub menu as I mentioned in a previous comment. From the text-only console, login and search for the uninstall script file (`cd /usr/share/ati/ && ls`), which is used to uninstall the AMD Catalyst driver from the AMD website.

Comment: From where do i get to the text-only console. It doesn't seem to be from the boot menu. PS thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. Then run this command and comment about the results: `cd /usr/share/ati/ && ls`. The command will tell you if there is a file called `fglrx-uninstall.sh` in the `/usr/share/ati/` directory. To reboot the system from the console run the command: `sudo shutdown -r now`. Press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to exit from the virtual console. In Ubuntu 17.10 and later press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to exit from the virtual console.
5. If there is an `fglrx-uninstall.sh` file, you can uninstall the AMD Catalyst driver and reboot by running: `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh && sudo reboot`. After you reboot, your computer will be using the open source graphics driver as it did before.
6. You can use the terminal program `xrandr` to create a custom resolution (in your case you want the native resolution of your monitor - 1366×768 pixels) by following the instructions in this link: [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol).

Comment: If there is an `fglrx-uninstall.sh` file, you can uninstall the AMD Catalyst driver and reboot by running: `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh && sudo shutdown -r now`. Then install the AMD graphics driver from the Ubuntu Software Center and reboot by running: `sudo apt-get install fglrx && sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Am sorry but I am not understanding at what state of my computer should i open the text-only console because i cannot do it when I start my computer normally because I cannot see anything.

Comment: You can open the text-only console from anywhere, so use the keyboard shortcut to open the text-only console from wherever you are, even if it's only a black screen it should work from there.

Comment: Aha i was missing the space between 'sh/usr'..thanks a lot Mr. Its downloading now from the sotware center.

Comment: Does the "input not supported" screenshot in my answer look like your "input not supported" screen that you saw?

Comment: Yes it looked like yours,  now the problem is solved, not completely though but its working as you said.

Comment: Now after the installation I am again having the same problem. Input not supported. How should i uninstall this one now?

Comment: You can uninstall fglrx by running `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*` . This will remove the proprietary graphics driver, so you will be using the open source graphics driver instead as you did before.

Comment: Sorry for dragging this so long but now that i am running on the open sourse driver, what is the way i can get the desired resolution.

Comment: From *Systems Settings* (red and white gear icon on the launcher) -> *Displays* -> *Resolution*. To the right of Resolution is a dropdown menu from which you can select from the list of available display resolutions. If there is a 1366×768 resolution in the dropdown menu, then you can select it. there is also a terminal program called `xrandr` that can do this, but the maximum resolution shown by `xrandr` is greater than the maximum resolution supported by my monitor, so I don't use xrandr.

Comment: Yes I've seen that option already, there are only two resolutions which are lower than required.

Comment: I would like to check the hardware specs of your computer, to find out if there is any available information about the display resolution. What is the model number of your computer if it is a laptop?

Comment: Acer=V193HQ, Graphic=Saphire Redeon 6450 1 GB, CPU=AMD FX 6300, Ram 4GB.

Comment: The Sapphire Radeon HD 6450 1GB graphics card supports digital monitors up to 1920x1200 resolution with a DVI connection monitor, possibly more than that with an HDMI connection monitor. The Acer V193HGL supports a maximum resolution of 1366×768, although possibly this is only when the DVI port is used. Since both your graphics card and your monitor have DVI ports, I suggest that you get or borrow a DVI-to-DVI cable if you don't already have one and try connecting the DVI port on your graphics card to the DVI port on your monitor. A DVI-to-DVI cable costs about $2.00 USD.

Comment: No my my Monitor  V193HQ does not have a DVI port, so will a DVI to VGA with an adapter will do?

Comment: It probably won't work because VGA is analog and DVI is digital. Yes, you will get a display, but I don't think it will improve the display resolution. Furthermore, if you ever have to get another monitor the same story is being repeated all over again, now that the HDMI connection is slowly replacing the DVI connection on new monitors, and also on some new computers such as the Intel NUC.

Comment: so there is no working around this?, what about creating a custom resolution? Or anything at all
Very thankful for you help.

Comment: I have already thought about using xrandr to create a custom resolution (in your case you want the native resolution of your monitor - 1366×768 pixels). The problem is that xrandr gives inaccurate results on my computer, so I don't want to do anything with xrandr on my computer, but here is a link: [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol)

Comment: a complicated problem. +1 for your effort