# Ubuntu has a heavily pixelated screen when I try to use it

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, graphics

I was going to install it and tried it out before actually going through with the installation, but when I did that, the desktop loaded up for a few seconds then became a heavily reddish-orange pixelated screen and froze that way. I restarted and tried it again and it did the same thing. All I did was move the mouse for a few seconds then it screwed up.

Is this a graphics card or some other hardware problem? And if it is, how do you fix it or is it completely incompatible? My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE and the processor is AMD Sempron 145. You can supposedly install drivers for stuff, but how can you do that when you can't use it to begin with?

Or is it a different problem entirely?

Comment: 4GB. I did a memory and disk test and it said that it passed with no errors, so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can get to a text-only console: [How to switch to a command-line console](http://askubuntu.com/questions/438783/how-to-switch-to-a-command-line-console) before your computer totally freezes, run `ubuntu-drivers devices` to get the package name of the recommended NVIDIA driver, and then install the recommended NVIDIA driver with `sudo apt-get install some-package-name`. All this is for after you have installed Ubuntu on your hard drive, of course.

Comment: Do you need the internet to do this? Because it doesn't recognize my USB adaptor.

Comment: You only need internet to download the NVIDIA graphics driver and maybe you need to download and install a package to get your computer to recognize your USB adaptor.

Comment: How can you put a driver for the adaptor that I use for wifi when you need the internet to install it? All I can think of is plugging in the ethernet cable.

Comment: The devices command doesn't work. It just starts a new line when I try it. ANd "autoinstall" doesn't work either, just says it doens't detect anything.

Comment: If you can't get a recommended NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver output from `ubuntu-drivers devices` then install the current NVIDIA driver -- *nvidia-current* .

Comment: The whole command is "sudo ubuntu nvidia-current", right?

Comment: The whole command is `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current && sudo reboot` . Type it all on one line and then press the Enter key to run it.

Comment: It also freezes on me sometimes before I can go to the console, but doesn't pixelate (only pixelates after I try to use it normally). Is there anything I can do after it freezes other than restart and hope it works?

Comment: Tried nvidia-current and it said that it wasn't able to locate the package. I tried to install a couple other things also to see if they'd work and it can't locate anything. Even if my graphics card is about fried, surely I can install some other program, right?

Comment: I installed 14.04 from ubuntu.com, so that's odd.

Comment: I got it working. When I installed it from the CD, I didn't have an internet connection since it couldn't detect my adaptor,  so I was missing a lot of update and upgrades that were needed to work right. So I did apt-get update and upgrade and was able to install the drivers afterwards. And now it doesn't freeze or pixelate anymore. I'm on Ubuntu right now typing this.... finally. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Plug in the ethernet cable so that you have an internet connection and start the computer.
2. Open a text-only console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
3. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Now you are logged in to a text-only console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. Run these commands to install the proprietary graphics driver for your NVIDIA GeForce 6150 SE GPU:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt install nvidia-current
   sudo reboot
   ```