# How to exit from TTY mode

Tags: kubuntu, gui, tty

I accidentally changed the video driver on my Kubuntu from NVIDIA to Xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, rebooted my PC and now my GUI does not load after GRIB. Instead of GUI, I can see TTY mode.

I logged to this mode, tried press CTRL + ALT + F7 and CTRL + ALT + FN + F7, tried enter "init 5"/"init 6" and all don't help!

How can I load my GUI?

Screen of TTY
[image: Screen of TTY]

Screen on Ubuntu Devices
[image: Screen on ubuntu devices]

Comment: I saw this solution, but it not works in my case. CTRL + ALT + F7 not working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch to a command-line console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438783/how-to-switch-to-a-command-line-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/)

Comment: @Mogli That duplicate doesn't work. Try the one after it.

Comment: I pressed each variants: Ctrl+Alt+F1/F6 (these variants change TTY From 1 to 6), Ctrl+Alt+F6/F12 (these variants don't change anything).
"sudo systemctl start lightdm.service" also without any effects

Comment: Do you have DE installed? What do you get when you run `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you! I don't know why, but this command installed me kubuntu-descktop, but after reboot I still saw TTY. Then I installed tasksel, installed sddm,  and run dpkg-reconfigure sddm.
BUT! Now I have issue with resolution of login screen. It's very-very big and  I don't know why... Maybe do you have any ideas?

Comment: I assume that sddm installs as the dependency of sddm. Not sure why it didn't install in the first place. If you have issues with resolution [ask](/questions/ask) a new question

Comment: What is the exact result of `sudo systemctl start lightdm.service` (or `systemctl status lightdm.service`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between virtual console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-virtual-console-and-gui)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have installed the wrong version of the nvidia driver, you need to remove unused drivers, since the tty console appears due to incompatibility of accidentally installed packages.

try removing:

`apt list --installed | grep nvidia`

`apt-get autoremove --purge name-your-driver`

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the lightdm service

`sudo service lightdm start`

If not installed use

`sudo apt install lightdm`

Answer (score 0):

I installed lightdm to try to resolve an NVIDIA driver issue, but it didn't, so I uninstalled it. Both the installation and the uninstall were done through the terminal, and then I restarted my PC and was stuck in TTY mode.

I uninstalled the NVIDIA drivers using the second command listed by @Fithe_Xanki, and installed and started lightdm using the two commands listed by @White Mars, and then the desktop opened normally.

So the lesson I learn from this is that you don't need to install lightdm on your Linux, but once installed it can't be removed anymore. Remembering I'm using Ubuntu.