# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS bootup screen blinking. Message: “/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks”

Tags: boot, nvidia, dell

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and it was working fine this morning. I took a break and powered it down. When I turned it on again, I got the following message on a flickering screen beyond which the boot process does not continue:

Message:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks
```

The *** represent big digits like 123456789

I tried to enter the terminal using Ctrl + F3 but I could not input any command because the screen kept flickering again. Occasionally, a letter would display on the screen.

Can anyone help, please?

I'm using DELL Inspiron 7577 with core i5, 7th gen intel CPU, and NVIDIA GTX 1060 GPU. I have an NVME drive as my main hard disk.

UPDATE: The bootup screen has stopped blinking and I see 4 OK's in green. But it has still been a long time and nothing is progressing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I used Ctrl + F3 to enter tty2, which asks for login. But it doesn't accept my login or password. I really don't know what to do here.

Comment: [How to switch to a command-line console](https://askubuntu.com/q/438783/)

Comment: @karel: Thanks for your comments, but the problem is that when I enter my username, I get a prompt that my login is incorrect, even though it is not incorrect. I never get past the stage of login

Comment: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/)

Comment: @karel: I tried that and reset my password by going into recovery mode > root. But the problem persists. I still keep seeing "incorrect login" error

Comment: I did that. I reset my password, but the same problem is there. My tty does not even ask for a password, it just says incorrect login. Even though I checked all the usernames list from the root when I was in the recovery mode, my username that I keep entering is present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered exactly the same problem after updating my Nvidia driver (and CUDA toolkit). Although the answer comes late, I'm recording it here so it might help someone.

Basically, it's the same problem concerning Nvidia drivers as in previous [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w).

The only difference is that, as the screen keeps blinking/flickring, it's impossible to switch to text ttys and uninstall/reinstall Nvidia drivers.

What worked for me was entering the recovery mode as root, and [uninstalling Nvidia drivers](https://partners-intl.aliyun.com/help/doc-detail/109111.htm) (Note that you need to manually run the uninstallation executables if you've installed CUDA and drivers manually using runfiles), and reinstalling.