# Shutting down the system using a virtual console

Tags: command-line, shutdown, reboot, virtual-console

My computer is freezing from time to time. It's because I make few mistakes and I ruined my system. I don't have any time to reinstall the system now. 
While my PC is frozen, it still works when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Is there any way to reboot system using it?

Comment: so, do you want shutdown / reboot use command line?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [How do I shut down or reboot from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-shut-down-or-reboot-from-a-terminal)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> brought you from X11 (the GUI) to a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). You can certainly reboot from here.

- **The easiest way** to reboot from a virtual console is to **just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>**. You don't even need to log in first, though it would not be a problem if you did. Unlike on the old DOS systems, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> in a GNU/Linux system like Ubuntu actually performs a proper shutdown and clean reboot.

  This doesn't work in the GUI (unless you've set it up to, or you're running a *really* old distro). But it does work in any virtual console that doesn't have X11 running in it (unless you've set it up not to, which is rare).
- Another way is to log in and run `sudo reboot`. You'll be asked for your password to log in on the virtual console, and you'll be asked for it again for `sudo`. It's the same password both times, and you won't see any placeholder characters (like `*`) appear as you're typing it. Type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, **instead of rebooting**, you might consider:

- *Restarting just the GUI.* Your desktop environment and all running programs will swiftly quit (so you must usually be as careful with this as with a reboot), the GUI will be restarted, and the graphical login screen will come back up, when you run:

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```

  This works by stopping and starting the [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)). That particular command actually only works if your display manager is [LightDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM), which it is by default on most Ubuntu systems. The main exception is if you are running Ubuntu GNOME, which uses [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager):

  ```
  sudo service gdm restart
  ```
- *Attempting to close just the offending program.* Though no program should cause the whole GUI to freeze, it can occasionally happen. You can log in (see above) and run [`top`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/top.1.html) see the currently running processes, sorted by CPU usage. (Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit `top` itself.) A program that's causing the GUI to freeze is not *necessarily* using lots of CPU, but this is a place to start.

  You can also use the [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html) command to find the process ID or name of a program you know you want to try to quit, and the [`kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/kill.1.html) or [`killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/killall.1.html) command to quit it by number or name, respectively. As suggested by its name, `killall` attempts to kill all processes that have the name you give it. (The name of a process is not necessarily the same as the name shown to you in its launcher icon or title bar.)

**Be careful when rebooting**, no matter how you do it:

- If you have programs with unsaved documents, your documents will be lost. If you need to attempt to save data first, then don't rush to reboot.
- And **this applies to restarting the display manager, too**, except for documents open in other virtual consoles (but *including* those open in terminals accessed through terminal *windows* on your graphical desktop).

*See also [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)*

Answer (score 7):

Run following command:

```
sudo reboot
```

Or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Both command will perform a reboot/restart on your system. If that does not work, hold the power key down for a couple of seconds, release it and press it again to start the pc.

If the system happens to running 16.04 release (you can check it with `lsb_release -r`), then no need for `sudo` privilege on restart command. Simply run `reboot` will do the jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Once in console mode, run the following:
`sudo init 6`

`init 6` basically tells the `init` process to shutdown all of the spawned processes/daemons as written in the init files (in the inverse order they started) and lastly invoke the `shutdown -r` now command to reboot the machine

Comment: Although this is a perfectly good answer and running `init 6` works fine, [just running `shutdown -r now` (or `reboot`) does all that same cleanup, too](https://askubuntu.com/a/175490/22949). On a modern GNU/Linux system, `init 6`, `shutdown -r now`, and `reboot` (though not `reboot -f`) [all execute the appropriate init scripts for stopping running daemons properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64385/11938), so there rarely any reason to prefer `init 6` over other methods.

Comment: I definitely agree, however shutdown and restart are part of upstart package. In case of something gone wrong and both being unavailable, init 6 is a foolproof way.

Comment: `init` is *also* provided by the `upstart` package, on releases where Upstart is installed by default. [As of 15.04, SystemD is used instead](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), and the `systemd-sysv` package provides `init`, `shutdown`, and `reboot`. It's possible but odd for `dpkg -S /sbin/{init,shutdown,reboot}` to show different packages for those three; do you have an Ubuntu system where it does? (`restart` *is* Upstart-specific, but [has nothing to do with rebooting](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/restart.8.html) and shouldn't be confused with `reboot`.)